# how to make a 2d array that is dynamic

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic

I am trying to make a 2-dimensional array that is semi-dynamic. So it does not use arrayLists and is not fully dynamic where the user can add or remove elements but the program must be able to ask the user for the number of teams then ask for the name of each team and the number of players per team and lastly the name of each player in each team. Below is what i have gotten done so far. The code runs but would not output the teams and players. Please help as soon as you can:)

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class semi_dynamic 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //Variable Declarations and Initializations
        String sNumPlayers="";
        int numPlayers=0, numTeams=0;
        //String sTeams[]=new String[3];
        String sPlayers[][] =new String[3][];//want an array of arrays but do not know how many teams players there are per team
        Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many teams are there:");
        numTeams=scanner.nextInt();
        String sTeams[]=new String [numTeams];
        for(int i=0;i<sTeams.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("\nPlease enter in team name #"+(i+1)+":");
            sTeams[i]=scanner.next();
        }//end for loop
        for(int i=0;i<sPlayers.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("\nHow many players are there in team "+sTeams[i]+":");
            sNumPlayers=scanner.next();
            numPlayers=Integer.parseInt(sNumPlayers);
            sPlayers[i]=new String[numPlayers];
            for(int j=0;j<sPlayers[i].length;j++)
            {
                System.out.println("\nPlease enter in team player #"+(j+1)+" for team "+sTeams[i]+":");
                sPlayers[i][j]=scanner.next();
            }//end for loop
        }//end for loop
        System.out.println("\n=====================================\nTEAMS                       PLAYERS\n");
        for(int i=0;i<sPlayers.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(sTeams[i]+"\t ");
            for (int j=0;j<sPlayers.length;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" "+sPlayers[i][j]+"\t ");
            }//end for loop
            System.out.println("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        }//end for loop
    }//end main
}//end class
```

Comment: `sPlayers = new String[numTeams][];` once you know how many teams; then `sPlayers[i] = new String[sNumPlayers];` (as you are already doing) when you have the number of players for team #`i`.

Answer (score 0):

First mistake:

```
String sPlayers[][] =new String[**3**][];
```

You are always trying to enter player names for 3 teams. Change it to:

```
    numTeams=scanner.nextInt();//also make sure to handle InputMismatchException for non integer inputs
    String sTeams[]=new String [numTeams];
    String sPlayers[][] =new String[numTeams][];//now it works for user entered number of teams
```

While printing player names of each team:

```
 for(int i=0;i<sPlayers.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(sTeams[i]+"\t ");
        for (int j=0;j< **sPlayers.length** ;j++)//j<numTeams, it should be j<num of players for each team
        {
            System.out.print(" "+sPlayers[i][j]+"\t ");
        }//end for loop
        System.out.println("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    }//end for loop
```

Change the innerloop's condition to sPlayer[i].length

```
    for(int i=0;i<sPlayers.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(sTeams[i]+"\t ");
        for (int j=0;j<sPlayers[i].length;j++)//now j<num of players of ith team
        {
            System.out.print(" "+sPlayers[i][j]+"\t ");
        }//end for loop
        System.out.println("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    }//end for loop
```